# eclipse - show most recently visited tabs in the editor

Tags: eclipse, editor

Is it possible to configure eclipse to order the tabs in the tab bar by most recent access time or something in those lines? The current behaviour is sort of not really comprehensible to me -- most of the time if I switch from tab1 (displaying file1) to e.g. tab2 (displaying file2) tab1 gets hidden in the >> thingy and some other tab, say tab42, which I haven't accessed in a long time, pops up in its place.

Comment: You want to active the most recently used (MRU) check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578197/eclipse-juno-tabs-repositionning

Comment: I set swt-mru-visible to true for my theme and now it seems like it works just fine, thanks a lot @pabrantes

Comment: You're welcome. I've also flagged your question as a duplicate (waiting for moderation, though). Meanwhile, you should post yourself an answer stating that this is a duplicate question and pointing the link I gave you, and accept it. I'm telling you to answer because I do not want to collect any reputation points for just pointing out a SO link, but it's better to not leave the question unanswered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pabrantes pointed out my question is actually a duplicate of [another so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578197/eclipse-juno-tabs-repositionning), which I wasn't able to find on my own due to my inadequate question statement.

Long story short: you just need to set `swt-mru-visible` to `true` in the `.MPartStack` section of the CSS file for your current theme.